# Managed Executor Service replacing Executor Service to use Container threads( jboss app server) instead of JVM

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I am using below Executor service which is using newFixedTreadPool of size 2.
I want instead of JVM, App server jboss to manage thread so plan on replacing ExecutorService to ManagedExecutorService. Question was is my understanding right here and if so can I pass newFixedThreadPool to managedExecutorService or just leave it to be managed by container. What is best and recommended Production-ready solution

```
Callable callableObj = () -> { 
  Map<String, String> dsTokenMap = //some function call; return dsTokenMap; }; 
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 2 ); 
Future future = service.submit( callableObj );

try { 
  Map result = future.get(500,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
  logDebug( "result from Async call is :::"+result ); } 
catch ( Exception ex ) {
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look quite right to me. You shouldn't create a new `ExecutorService` within a callable.

Comment: ExecutorService is outside callable. Question is 

I am using below Executor service which is using newFixedTreadPool of size 2. I want instead of JVM, App server jboss to manage thread so plan on replacing ExecutorService to ManagedExecutorService. Question was is my understanding right here and if so can I pass newFixedThreadPool to managedExecutorService or just leave it to be managed by container. What is best and recommended Production-ready solution

Comment: Oh I see. The format just looked odd :) Anyway it's always a better idea to use the `MangaedExecutorService` which can be injected in managed beans. The context will be setup correctly for the threads. If you use your own `ExecutorService` you need to setup the context for the thread itself.